# Manipulating DOM in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am aware that manipulating DOM directly in react is not a considered a good practice. As react reconciliation engine will hit performance when comparing virtual DOM and real DOM

But what if I do something like this?

**Scenario shown only to explain question. No answer is needed for this specific scenario but to this practice as general with the downsides**

Scenario: 1

```
state = {
   innerHTML : ""
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.state.innerHTML

handleChange(){
  //...handles change in state
}
```

Scenario: 2

```
state = {
    color:"red"
}

document.getElementById("test").style.color = this.state.color

handleChange(color){
    this.setState({color})
}
```

In such as scenario react is aware that it needs to re-render as I am changing the state there-by **maintaining the consistency of both Virtual and Real DOM**.

**So in all such situations where I can use state to maintain consistency and make changes to real DOM is it still a bad idea to make changes to real DOM in this way?**

Comment: Yes, direct DOM manipulation in React is very anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, rather than setting `innerHTML` directly, you should be using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  state = {
    innerHTML: '',
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({ innerHTML: '...' });
  }

  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: this.state.innerHTML } }></div>;
  }
}
```

As stated in the docs:

> [**dangerouslySetInnerHTML**](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)
>
> `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React’s replacement for using `innerHTML` in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and pass an object with a `__html` key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

Also, when using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, React will ignore that part of the DOM when diffing the virtual DOM and the real DOM ([reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)), so it will be more performant as it has less work to do.

And in any case, if you do:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = this.state.innerHTML;
```

At some point in your code, maybe in `componentDidUpdate()`, and then `render()` is called again (when you update the state or a parent component re-renders), your changes will be overwritten, so you would need to be constantly updating it, which might produce a small but noticeable flash and reduce performance, as each render will have to update the DOM 2 times (one from React and the other one from `innerHTML`).

Comment: Better yet, use one of the libraries that avoids the use of dSIH.

Comment: I am aware of that. But I used this example to ask about such a scenario being a valid solution or not. I am not facing this problem specifically. But thanks for the effort:)

Comment: @kooskoos Check the updated answers, I have added more details about the disadvantages of the approach you were asking about.

Comment: As I see it is setState is async. So when I setState that change will not take place immediately then the real DOM would be changed and when react re-renders virtual DOM will also change. Thereby maintaining consistency with no flash.

Comment: Would you also check the scenario I have added to change the style directly in DOM

Answer (score 2):

you can look into using ReactRef instead of having to manipulate the DOM directly, it's easier, safer and more best practice.

check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: I wanted to know whether this would be a good idea or not. I am already aware of the alternative solutions. Thanks for the help:)