# Modifying the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React only **re-renders when there is a change in state**.

So why is that I see the changes I have made to real DOM directly?

I understand I am modifying the real DOM, but what is triggering the re-render when I have not changed the state at all.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 id="header">Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
document.getElementById("header").style.color = "red";
```

Sanbox url https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-chatelet-hbpmw

**I assumed react re-renders whenever it sees changes in VirtualDOM, it clearly re- renders in this scenario.**

My question is **what is triggering the reconciliation engine** so that react figures out the change and re-renders?

One explanation would be the entire DOM re-renders normally and react has a stale copy of the DOM.

But in that case I suppose this should happen

**- When next time react renders it should think it has an updated copy 
and change the color   back to black.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulating DOM in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569696/manipulating-dom-in-react)

Comment: You can use - `forceUpdate` to re-render DOM forcefully. To know more - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: @DrewReese that question was asked by me only. Both of them are different with somewhat similar title:)

Comment: @AlokMali Why would I use forceUpdate() the DOM has already been updated. My question is how?

Comment: What makes you think react is re-rendering anything? Drop a `console.log('render');` in your `index.js` just before the return and you'll see only one log, react rendered once. The manipulation of the DOM directly is outside of react's "view" and anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I already added a follow up question at the bottom. Do check it out.

Comment: That is simple to test. What did you try to test what happens the next time react renders?

Comment: It doesn't change. The question is how does react figure out which copy is the newest? RealDOM or VIrtualDOM

Comment: @kooskoos, I think it is because once the application is loaded, all the things of App.js being executed. - https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-sammet-fluup

Comment: Yes that is true. I am already doing the same thing but the question is how does react figure which DOM has the most recent changes virtual or real one?

Comment: Short of getting a facebook dev here to explain the inner workings of react the quick answer is that react works on its own VirtualDOM only. State or props update, react updates the VDOM, pushes the updated view to the DOM. To quote directly from the docs, "When a component’s props or state change, React decides whether an actual DOM update is necessary by comparing the newly returned element with the previously rendered one. When they are not equal, React will update the DOM. This process is called “reconciliation”." [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#reconciliation)

Answer (score 2):

React doesn't re-create the whole real-DOM tree, but only updates the properties that have changed in the virtual DOM, which is the whole purpose of using a virtual DOM.

The word "render" is used ambiguously sometimes, but here it means *render the virtual DOM*, and not *render the real DOM*.

What you see on the screen is always the real DOM, so if you change the real DOM directly, you see that change immediately, but React is not involved here at all.

If you change the real DOM directly, then React doesn't know anything about that change, and doesn't re-render. The virtual DOM is not changed.

When React re-renders the next time (for any other reason),
React checks if the `color` has changed in its virtual DOM, but the `color` in the virtual DOM has *not* changed, is was `black` and is still `black`,
so React does not update the `color` in the real DOM, but just leaves it untouched as it is right now, which is `red`.